# cocos2d Iphone Game structure

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I have 2 question belongs to structuring the game scene , layer. In my game I used separate scene for Menu and Game. Menu scene hold many layers like main menu scene  have a connection to settings layer & levels layer.

```
MENU SCENE (stack of multiple layers main Layer , Levels Layer , Settings Layer)
 1. Main Layer
    - play Button
    - Levels Button   -> Load Level Layer
    - Settings Button -> Load Settings Layer
    - Help
 2. Levels Layer
    - Level 1 Button -
    - Level 2 Button  | -> Replace the MENU SCENE with GAME SCENE 
    - Level N Button - 
 3. Settings Layer

GAME SCENE (Stack of Game layer & status menu layers sits on the top)

  1. Game Layer

  2. Status Menu layer
    - Score Label
    - Reset Level Button
    - Main Menu Button
```

1. How to use common background image for both Menu scene and game scene?
2. Please validate the above structuring is it good enough in scalability preceptive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. A good aproach, would be using 2 Layes on your scenes, a BackGroundLayer and a GamePlayLayer, then u could use the same BackGroundlayer on each of your scenes. Or use just one scene and BackGroundLayer and just switch the Gameplay Scenes.
2. You can create use a Delegate calling a method in the Main Menu file.
   I would encorage you to create an GameManager Class, that would handle that

I notice your structure is a bit wrong, a good one would be:

```
Main Scene
 Main Layer
  - play Menu Button
  - Levels Menu   -> Level (Player shall choose level?) (store an id to identify witch level will be used
  - Settings -> Settings Menu (Change ur settings?)
  - Help Menu
```

When the player chooses a level it will store in a Constant witch level the player will be playing and when he hits the play button u just load one scene for all levels, and just change the GamePlay Layer.

There is a really great book that explore a hole chapter talking about GameManager, Menus  and stuff. i Really encorage you to buy it.

http://cocos2dbook.com/ - (Learning Cocos2D: A Hands-On Guide to Building iPhone and iPad Games with Cocos2D, Box2D, and Chipmunk)

It will be finished in July i guess, but u can buy the rougth cut... i did, its really good pdf always updates http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/iphone/9780132180863

Again, a really good book. i read it.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. I have one more question if I understand correct your sugession is to use one scene for whole game and i couldn't find the GamePlay Layer. Please clarify , at present am following this book http://www.apress.com/9781430233039 for sure I will read the other book you have suggested too. Thanks for for the comments.

Comment: Yes- I misunderstood that you are recommending to use single scene for the whole game. Got you. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, i was going to right more on the comment above, but submited by mistake :P but yes, i Scene for the gameplay.

Comment: Lets despise the menus, u will have a GameScene : CCScene Right? In that you will 2 Sets o Layers, a backgroundLayer (that you will not change) and some Gameplay Layers (GamePlayLevel1, GamePlayLevel2, GamePlayLevel3) .... in the init u create the backgroundLayer and add as a child. and using a switch (that u have choosed on your menu) u get the case, like leve1, and then add the GamePlayLevel1 to the scene :)

Comment: Rite now I have loaded the background as you mentioned with game scene status bar for displaying score's , button for switching back to menu screen. Yet to start the multiple level design for now I have just one level :). between I have modified the structure in my main thread , can you clarify this is what your suggestion.